# What's the best way of re-using classification rules for multiple queries within big query standard SQL?

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm using Big Query to analyse Google Analytics data.

I need to classify visits dependent on whether they visit particular URLs that indicate they were in the booking process or purchased etc.

There is a long list of URLs that represent each step and hence it would be advantageous to include the classifications within a view and re-use with appropriate joins for whatever query requires the classification.

I have the following view that seems to do what I need:

```
SELECT
  fullVisitorId,
  visitID,
  LOWER(h.page.pagePath) AS path,
  CASE
    WHEN
      LOWER(h.page.pagePath) = '/' THEN '/'
    WHEN
      LOWER(h.page.pagePath) LIKE '{path-here}%' OR
      ....  ....  ....
    ELSE 'other'
    END
  AS path_classification,
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS date
FROM
  `{project-id}.{data-id}.ga_sessions_*`, UNNEST(hits) AS h
WHERE
  REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'[0-9]{8}')
AND
  h.type = 'PAGE'
```

I'm wondering if there's a simpler way of achieving this that doesn't require selecting from a pre-existing table as this doesn't seem necessary to define the classifications. I get the feeling that it's possible to use something more straight forward, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Does anyone know how to put these definitions into a view without querying a table within the view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider simple example:

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '123' AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '234' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '456' 
)
SELECT 
  id,
  path,
  CASE path
    WHEN '123' THEN 'a'
    WHEN '234' THEN 'b'
    WHEN '345' THEN 'c'
    ELSE 'other'
  END AS path_classification
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY id
```

Above can be refactored into below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '123' AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '234' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '456' 
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  path,
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath = path  LIMIT 1), 
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath IS NULL LIMIT 1)
  ) AS path_classification
FROM yourTable, 
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<cpath STRING, crule STRING>(path, rule)) AS rules
   FROM `project.dataset.rules`) AS r
ORDER BY id
```

which relies on `rules` view that is defined as below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT '123' AS path, 'a' AS rule UNION ALL
SELECT '234', 'b' UNION ALL
SELECT '345', 'c' UNION ALL
SELECT NULL, 'other'
```

As you can see all classification rules are only in `rules` view!

You can play around this approach with below  :

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '123' AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '234' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '456' 
),
rules AS (
  SELECT '123' AS path, 'a' AS rule UNION ALL
  SELECT '234', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT '345', 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 'other'
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  path,
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath = path  LIMIT 1), 
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath IS NULL LIMIT 1)
  ) AS path_classification
FROM yourTable, 
  (SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<cpath STRING, crule STRING>(path, rule)) AS rules 
   FROM rules) AS r
ORDER BY id
```

this can be further "simplified" by moving `ARRAY_AGG` inside view as below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<cpath STRING, crule STRING>(path, rule)) AS rules 
FROM (
  SELECT '123' AS path, 'a' AS rule UNION ALL
  SELECT '234', 'b' UNION ALL
  SELECT '345', 'c' UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, 'other'
)
```

In this case final query is as simple as below

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  id, 
  path,
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath = path  LIMIT 1), 
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath IS NULL LIMIT 1)
  ) AS path_classification
FROM yourTable, rules AS r
ORDER BY id
```

Depends on your specific rules - above can /should be adjusted/optimized respectively - but I hope this gives you a main direction

> Q in comment: does your solution enable the use of matching with the LIKE keyword or matching with regex?

Original question was - `What's the … way of re-using classification rules for multiple queries within big query standard SQL?`

So above examples in my initial answer just show you how to make this happen (focus on “reuse”)

How you will use it (matching with the LIKE keyword or matching with regex) is totally up to you!

See example below
Take a look at `path_classification_exact_match` vs `path_classification_like_match` vs `path_classification_regex_match`

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH yourTable AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, '123' AS path UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, '234' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, '345' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, '456' UNION ALL
  SELECT 5, '234abc' UNION ALL
  SELECT 6, '345bcd' UNION ALL
  SELECT 7, '456cde' 
),
rules AS (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(STRUCT<cpath STRING, crule STRING>(path, rule)) AS rules 
  FROM (
    SELECT '123' AS path, 'a' AS rule UNION ALL
    SELECT '234', 'b' UNION ALL
    SELECT '345', 'c' UNION ALL
    SELECT NULL, 'other'
  )
)
SELECT 
  id, 
  path,
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath = path  LIMIT 1), 
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath IS NULL LIMIT 1)
  ) AS path_classification_exact_match,
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE path LIKE CONCAT('%',rr.cpath,'%')  LIMIT 1), 
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath IS NULL LIMIT 1)
  ) AS path_classification_like_match,
  IFNULL(
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(path, rr.cpath)  LIMIT 1), 
    ( SELECT rr.crule FROM UNNEST(r.rules) AS rr WHERE rr.cpath IS NULL LIMIT 1)
  ) AS path_classification_regex_match
FROM yourTable, rules AS r
ORDER BY id
```

Output is:

```sql
id  path    path_classification_exact_match path_classification_like_match  path_classification_regex_match  
1   123     a                               a                               a    
2   234     b                               b                               b    
3   345     c                               c                               c    
4   456     other                           other                           other    
5   234abc  other                           b                               b    
6   345bcd  other                           c                               c    
7   456cde  other                           other                           other
```

Hope this helps :o)

Comment: @goose - did you have chance to try? any comments?

Comment: that's funny I don't seem to have been notified that you commented. I apologise for not making quicker progress on this. Although I'm a little confused by what you've written I believe it is what I'm looking for, I just need a little more time to apply it and understand it.

Many thanks for your detailed answer, it seems as if it's going to be very helpful.

Comment: sure. no problem! keep you time

Comment: Hi @Mikhaik - some of the features are a little new to me i.e the structs. I'm sure I can pick my way though understanding this though. Tell me in the meantime, does your solution enable the use of matching with the LIKE keyword or matching with regex? It's so far unclear to me how I would slot these in.

Comment: @goose - sure no problem. see addition in my answer! Hope now you will get it :o)

Comment: Ah penny drop! Thanks again @Mikhail , much appreciated. This is going to save me buckets of time as many queries will likely depend on these rules. Being able to re-configure in one place is a big win.

Comment: @goose - i am glad we did this :o)

Comment: Mikhail! Is this question one for you? :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51248318/how-to-define-a-bq-view-that-references-wildcard-tables-within-subqueries

Comment: @goose - missed this one  - will check it for you later in a day

Comment: Thx Mikhail - pls let me know if you think it shd be possible.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you may be interested in [`WITH` clauses](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#with_clause), which let you compose queries without having to use subqueries. For example,

```
#standardSQL
WITH Sales AS (
  SELECT 1 AS sku, 3.14 AS price UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS sku, 1.00 AS price UNION ALL
  SELECT 3 AS sku, 9.99 AS price UNION ALL
  SELECT 2 AS sku, 0.90 AS price UNION ALL
  SELECT 1 AS sku, 3.56 AS price
),
ItemTotals AS (
  SELECT sku, SUM(price) AS total
  FROM Sales
  GROUP BY sku
)
SELECT sku, total
FROM ItemTotals;
```

If you want to compose expressions, you can use [`CREATE TEMP FUNCTION`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions) statements to provide "macro-like" functionality:

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION LooksLikeCheese(s STRING) AS (
  LOWER(s) IN ('gouda', 'gruyere', 'havarti')
);

SELECT
  s1,
  LooksLikeCheese(s1) AS s1_is_cheese,
  s2,
  LooksLikeCheese(s2) AS s2_is_cheese
FROM (
  SELECT 'spam' AS s1, 'ham' AS s2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'havarti' AS s1, 'crackers' AS s2 UNION ALL
  SELECT 'gruyere' AS s1, 'ice cream' AS s2
);
```