# How to define a BQ view that references wildcard tables within subqueries?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a query that I wish to turn into a view. The query depends on several subqueries and looks something like this:

```
WITH subquery1 AS (
  date,
  key1,
  key2,  
  other_fields,
  ....
), subquery2 AS (
  date,
  key1,
  key2,  
  other_fields,
  ....
)

SELECT
  date,
  key1,
  key2,
  other_fields...
FROM table
JOIN subquery1 USING(key1, key2)
JOIN subquery2 USING(key1, key2)
```

Each of the subqueries references the same Google Analytics session data which is divided into 'data partitioned' tables, those tables that have the same table prefix and the suffix 'yyyymmdd' referenced in a date field.

I wish for the view to be able to select the relevant date table partitions within all sub-queries and when querying the table directly as in the query shown.

I have no working code - I am starting to think that this isn't possible, possibly because it involves correlated sub-queries.

Is this not possible? Or if it is possible, what sort of structure/syntax would achieve it?

**Update**

The motivation is to limit the amount of data that is selected in the query. In picking just a few recent dates I can limit the amount of data selected from 500GBs to tens of GBs.

To re-iterate - these aren't formally date partitioned tables, they are a series of individual tables with common prefixes all ending in yyyymmdd format. I have no problem selecting a range of these, but this doesn't help me for defining a view, I don't think.

**Update 2**

Here's what I've tried, but querying with varying dates doesn't affect the amount of data selected:

```
WITH revenue AS(
  SELECT DISTINCT 
    key1,
    key2,
    date,
    transactions,
    revenue
  FROM `project.dataset.revenue` AS main
)

SELECT
  _TABLE_SUFFIX AS date,
  main.key1 AS m_fvi,
  main.key2 AS m_vi,
  revenue.transactions,
  revenue.revenue
FROM `project.dataset.ga_sessions_*` AS main
LEFT JOIN revenue USING(key1, key2)
WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'[0-9]{8}')
```

Consuming query:

```
SELECT  
  *
FROM `project.dataset.view`
WHERE date = '20180701'
```

Selects same quantity of data as:

```
SELECT  
  *
FROM `project.dataset.view`
```

It should select roughly 1000th of the data which is inline with the number of 'partitions' that are within ga_sessions_*

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand your question completely. What makes a dat table partition relevant for a query? The time it was constructed? Have you tried using _PARTITIONTIME in the following manner? eg `... WHERE
  _PARTITIONTIME BETWEEN TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(TIMESTAMP_SUB(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(), INTERVAL 7 * 24 HOUR),DAY)
  AND TIMESTAMP_TRUNC(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),DAY);` Here is some additional documentation about querying partitioned tables https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-partitioned-tables

Comment: Thanks for your response Lisa - I've added some clarification in my question. The schema is the GA export schema https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en I don't think these are partitions in the formal sense of it (I explain in the clarification). They're relevant because they will help to limit the amount of data I need to select. I just can't figure out how to thread it through the sub-queries of the view.

Comment: You just need to include `_TABLE_SUFFIX` in the SELECT list and give it a different name.

Comment: Thanks for your input @ElliottBrossard - I'm not sure where I've gone wrong. I've shown my 'best attempt' in an update to the question. It uses _TABLE_SUFFIX but still selects all the data from all underlying partitions.

Comment: Hi! Were you able to solve the issue with the comments suggestions or you are still trying to fix the query?

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda I thought of a work around for my specific problem. None of the suggestions solve the problem (from what I can tell). I’d still be interested in a solution if anybody knows how to do this, my workaround isn’t very flexible.

Comment: One question then. In the `Update 2`, when you say "It should select roughly 1000th of the data" are you referring to bytes processed/billed or number of rows the queries output?

Comment: @GuillermoCacheda thanks for your interest in my question. It was bytes billed.

Comment: Check the answer I posted. I don't know if it's better than the specific workaround you implemented, but I think it addresses the confusion about the view and the queries selecting the same amount of data

Answer (score 0):

User @ElliottBrossard proposed in a comment to use [`_TABLE_SUFFIX`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#scanning_a_range_of_tables_using_table_suffix). This is the correct approach to what you were trying to do. The confusion comes when querying the view and the expected billing results.

The view is created correctly using `_TABLE_SUFFIX`. It gets the correct data from the correct tables and puts them in a new view. Now, the query with the `WHERE` clause is run:

```
SELECT *
FROM `project.dataset.view`
WHERE date = '20180701'
```

This query will read the whole view consisting of all of the tables that matched the regex `REGEXP_CONTAINS(_TABLE_SUFFIX, r'[0-9]{8}')` and then filter out the results that didn't match the `WHERE` clause. The second query does essentially the same minus the filtering. This means that the amount of data that BigQuery is processing is the same in both queries, resulting in the same amount being billed for both of them.

What I understand as a solution for this would be to create a view for each table with a suffix like `'yyyymmdd'`. This way, when you query the view of the timestamp you need, BigQuery will process less amount of data.

Comment: I see, so not a nice solution, but you've highlighted why it's happening. The regex is included because this is data from a Google Analytics feed. Two of the tables will be intra day data that I don't want to select. Would a solution for my specific case be to remove the regex and then in a later part of the query to remove the table suffixes that don't have the form 'yyyymmdd'?

Comment: You can filter them out with the regex (if that's possible in your case), [querying the suffixes you need](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables#querying_all_tables_in_a_dataset) or elsewhere in the query. 
If the query you are using to create the view effectively filters those two tables out, when you query the view you'll not get billed for the data of those two tables. That data won't be in the view, so BigQuery won't need to process it.